# Which data type is more suitable for fixed length of data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have fixed length data in **MYSQL** Database.

So my question is that which data type among the **VARCHAR** and **CHAR** is more suitable to be used with respect to performance, Space, Time and speed?

Comment: Go through this, https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field it might help you.

Comment: On the face of it, CHAR would seem more suitable

Answer (score 1):

since you have data is of fixed length you should use the CHAR.

For example:

The following statement creates a table with a CHAR column having the fixed length. i.e. CHAR(3) fixed length is 3.

**CREATE TABLE mysql_char_test (
    status CHAR(3)
);**